# Coxeter presentation of Hyperoctahedral group $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n \rtimes S_n$.

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, semidirect-product, coxeter-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

I know that the hyperoctahedral group $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n \rtimes S_n$ has the presentation

$$\langle s_{\text{1}},\ldots,s_n\mid s_{\text{1}}^{\text{2}}=s_i^2=1, (s_1s_2)^4=(s_is_{i+1})^3=(s_is_j)^2=1~| ~2\leq i\leq n, i+2\leq j\leq n \rangle,$$

where the generator $s_1$ is the diagonal matrix with a $-1$ in the top left entry and $1$s on the rest of the diagonal entry and $s_i$ are the permutation matrix formed from the identity switching both the $i-1$st and $i$th rows and corresponding columns.

> Where can I get a proof for this?

Comment: You mean a proof if your representation is correct?

Comment: yes.. this is the coxeter representation which can be obtained from the coxeter graph. I need an explicit proof for this without depending anything on root systems and simple systems.

Comment: What homomorphism defines the semidirect product?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer *per se* but a few places to look, according to *"Generators and Relations for Discrete Groups (Reprint of Fourth Edition),"* by H. S. M. Coxeter and W. O. J. Moser, page 90, are:

- Nielsen, J. (1924b), *"Die Isomorphismengruppen der freien Gruppen,"* Math. Ann. **91**, 169-209. This has a result that the group "may be regarded as the symmetry group of the $n$-dimensional Cartesian frame."
- Young, A. (1930), *"On quantitative substitutional analysis, "* Proc. London Math. Soc. (2), **31**, 273-388. This is where the group got its name.

The next two together show how the group "can be generated by two generators":

- Neumann, B. H. (1932), *"Die Automorphismengruppe der freien Gruppen,"* Math. Ann. **107**, 370-373.
- Coxeter, H. S. M. and Todd, J. A. (1936),  *"Abstract definitions for the symmetric groups of the regular polytopes in terms of two generators. Part I: The complete groups,"* Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. **32**, 199.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've just noticed that a synonym for hyperoctrahedral group is ["signed symmetric group"](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Signed_symmetric_group), so I might be able to help more in the near future!